How can I enable HTTPS support for localhost?
I am new to Helidon, and we want our Java app to support HTTPS for REST calls. I have a sample controller that returns some string, and my app currently runs on http://localhost:8080. How can I enable HTTPS and configure SSL?
Sample controller:
@Path("/test")
@ApplicationScoped
public class TestEndpointController {

    @GET
    public Response executeRule() {
        return Response.status(200).entity("Working").build();
    }
}

Here's what I tried:
Generated self signed certificate and configured it in the application.yaml file:
server:
 port: 8080
  host: 0.0.0.0
  ssl:
    private-key:
      keystore-resource-path: "keystore.p12"
      keystore-passphrase: "changeit"
  experimental:
    http2:
      enable: true
      max-content-length: 16384

Command used to generate cert
keytool -genkeypair -alias localhost -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 365
But when I try to hit the endpoint with https I am getting below error
This site can’t provide a secure connection

[edit] the question and add a [mre].

@aled I have added the necessary details.

A startup log trace showing the starting of tls on port 8080 would be helpful.

What version of Helidon are you using? The config in your question may be old - see Configuring TLS in the Config File - from the v4.0 documentation. (Also, I think http2 is no longer "experimental" in Helidon).

Your config seems to be Helidon 2.x syntax, is that a desired version you want to use?(latest is 4.x).
4.x https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/tree/4.0.11/examples/microprofile/tls
https://helidon.io/docs/v4/se/webserver#_configuring_tls
2.x https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/tree/2.6.7/examples/microprofile/tls
https://helidon.io/docs/v2/mp/jaxrs/02_server-configuration
server:
  tls:
    #Truststore setup
    trust:
      keystore:
        passphrase: "password"
        trust-store: true
        resource:
          resource-path: "keystore.p12"
    #Keystore with private key and server certificate
    private-key:
      keystore:
        passphrase: "password"
        resource:
          resource-path: "keystore.p12"

